# Does "in fair health" actually mean "unhealthy"?

Tags: word-meaning, expressions

http://us.movember.com/mens-health says:

> **12.1%** of men 18 years and over are **in fair or poor health**.

What is the meaning of "in fair health" here?

For me "in fair health" sounds like "healthy".
But it makes no sense that healthy+unhealthy people would make only 12.1% of the population.

So, does "in fair health" mean "unhealthy but not as unhealthy as poor health"?

[image: Movember Men's health]

Comment: Typically, the ranks are poor, fair, average, good, and excellent when talking generally about a data distribution for a magazine article. It can vary though. You're correct in thinking fair is better than poor but not considered good health.

Answer (score 1):

If you check this definition of [***fair***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/fair) sense 12:

> 12) neither very bad nor very good; average   ⇒ "in fair condition"

so it ends up being a neutral description. Neither bad (having a serious health condition) nor good (having healthy habits like diet, exercise, vaccinations, etc.).

In high school (for me anyway), a "fair" grade was a "C" 70-80%. Good enough to pass but nothing to brag about.

Comment: If fair here means average, then we can classify people as: poor health, average health, good health. How can poor+average only make 12.1% of the population? Is really 87.9% of the population so healthy they can brag about it? Just trying to understand better.

Comment: One would have to check the data that led to that conclusion. In the case of health I imagine there are lots of variables, so it depends how they judged it.

Comment: +1 With the lack of any scale being given on the linked article I think an assumption of 'fair meaning average/neutral/middling' is about right however it's often used in a scale as just a little better than average (rather like your school grade). It's not a great term to describe someone's health without actually defining what it means.